# Homestead quests are missing

Tags: assassins-creed-3

According to [this guide](http://www.gamersheroes.com/assassins-creed-3-guide-homestead-guide), every homestead quest from 18 on is missing. I thought they might be in later sequences, but no one popped up until the very end.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem by myself:

In quest 18, the blacksmith needs some new tools from a general store in New York. Although there is **no quest icon in New York**, the tools are available in one of those stores. After you deliver him those items, the other quests will be available.

Answer (score 0):

The game appears to be bugged. Homestead missions need to be completed in the sequence they become available (starting with sequence 5), or your companions lose the ability to level up. I don't think 100% completion is possible if you wait to level up your homestead due to this bug, which I find infuriating.